# PHP/Apache2: How do I redirect ./index.php?facebook to ./facebook.php?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Is it possible to redirect ./index.php?facebook to ./facebook.php? If so, how to do this?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Still can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do it.

- With Apache's `mod_rewrite`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =facebook [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)/index.php$ $1/facebook.php [R,L]
```

- Within the `index.php` PHP script itself (my PHP is very rusty; consider this to be pseudo-code):

```
    if (isset($_GET['facebook'])) {
        header('Location: facebook.php');
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it just won't work (Apache2 method). I'm not getting any errors in Apache2 logs...